# Apply nine patch to irregular shaped images in android

Tags: android

I am struggling to apply a nine patch to a image in android.I dint find android documentation that explanatory.Following is the image that i want to apply a nine patch.I dont have proper understanding of nine patch as i am a newbie to android.The saw like structure is getting stretched on larger screen sizes.If some one could provide nice useful links on how to create nine patch in android would be great help.Isnt there any app or tool that automatically creates a nine patch on images?Also can we apply a nine patch on a circular image?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend
Check out these tutorials:

http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoCDFQnWrt8